# Authorization Token for BOX API V2 obtained using scheduled script from Netsuite

Tags: javascript, box-api, netsuite

I am using Box V1 API in conjunction with scheduled scripts (javascript) running in Netsuite

With the new V2 API and Authorization procedure, can I obtain Authorization Tokens without any user interface being required?

Does anyone have an idiots guide (ie for me) to the steps required to obtain a valid token.

Answer (score 0):

Andy, with the V2 API the user *must* log in to Box and confirm that your application can access his/her data.  Box has put together an [authentication primer](http://developers.box.com/docs/#oauth-2) to walk you through the process.  Once authorized, you'll receive an access token and a refresh token for the user. Your scheduled scripts can use the refresh token to indefinitely update the access token.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I have the authorization procedure working with refresh tokens now.

Comment: Great!  If you feel that my answer told you what you needed to know, I'd appreciate it if you could accept it as correct.  Thanks!